# PHPMD avoid static access to parent

Tags: php, oop, static, code-cleanup, phpmd

Is there a way to avoid the `parent::` static accessor in PHP classes, or is this one of those times to use `@SuppressWarnings(StaticAccess)`?

On the same lines, it seems like this `StaticAccess` warning is popping in suspicious places.  Exception handling, for instance - when I `throw new Exception(...)`, PHPMD complains about static access.  But...there's not really another way to do it (that I've found) so I've got more warnings suppressors than I'd like.  Is this normal?

**EDIT**

As requested, here's an example - it's pretty straightforward:

```
class aaa {
    private $someReasonForAnException = true;

    public function __construct() {
        echo 'AAA<br>';
        if ($this->someReasonForAnException) {
            throw new Exception("Something happened that's worth noticing!");
        }
    }
}

class bbb extends aaa {    
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'BBB<br>';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$BBB = new bbb();
```

PHPMD will report two errors with the above: a `StaticAccess` error on the `Exception`, and a `StaticAccess` error on the `parent::__construct()` call.

To avoid that, I've got to notate both classes with `@SuppressWarnings` , which seems clunky, and also won't show "real" static access problems.

Comment: Post your code please...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos - thanks for taking a look, there's an example.

Comment: You're not making any static calls; I would report this as a bug.

Comment: Fwiw, I've made a pull request [here](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/pull/104) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way to reference parent's method implementation on PHP. There is nothing wrong with your code, PHPMD is drunk. The only problem you'd have with static access is because PHP allows you to call an instance method as a static method if it does not reference `$this` variable, but there is no point on doing so. You can ignore this kind of warning.

## Edit:

If you have something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}
```

PHP will allow you to do:

```
Foo::bar(); // works
```

But if you have this:

```
class Foo {
    private $bar = 'bar';
    public function bar() {
        echo $this->bar;
    }
}

Foo::bar(); // fatal error
```

Comment: Good news then, I suppose.  Could you explain `PHP allows you to call an instance method as a static method if it does not reference $this variable, but there is no point on doing so.` a little differently? I don't quite get your point.  Do you mean, PHP will call the instantiation as a static method, by default?

Answer (score 5):

A simple and sustainable solution might be to

- [override the Clean Code ruleset](http://phpmd.org/documentation/creating-a-ruleset.html)
- set the "exceptions" property on the StaticAccess rule to [include self and parent](http://phpmd.org/rules/cleancode.html#staticaccess):

Answer (score 0):

Because I use a lot of self:: for constants, change phpmd code to accept self:: and parent::.

In the program PHP/PMD/Rule/CleanCode/StaticAccess.php at line 36, change to:

```
if ($this->isReferenceInParameter($reference)
    || $reference->getImage() === 'self' 
    || $reference->getImage() === 'parent' 
    ) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Great, but what about when you have to update PHPMD? ;)